# How to resolve the org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities `BatchFcm` and `FcmTopics`. One FcmTopic can belong to many BatchFcm, so it has a `@ManyToOne` relation. I try to save the batchFcm but its not getting saved.

I have already tried putting

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) 
FcmTopics fcmTopics
```

I even tried `CascadeType.ALL`. But that is not my requirement.
The fcmtopics table will have data already inserted in it, I need to pick one and set in the batchfcm database.

I tried the `@Transient` annotation, it worked but the fcmTopics in column always remains null. I want the column with the id of fcmtopics in it.
Th Transient does stop mapping the field fcmtopics into a json data when retrieved from a controller. But I do want to retrieve it.

Here are my entities

> BatchFcm

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "batch_fcm")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BatchFcm extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    private FCMTopics fcmTopics;
```

> FcmTopics

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fcm_topics")
@Getter
@Setter
public class FCMTopics extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    private String description;

    private FCMTopicStatus status;
```

When i use `CascadeType` i get a constraintViolation exception with the duplicate key, I know it is due to the `unique = true` . Below is my Service

```
BatchFcm fcmDetail;
if (adminFcmResource.getId() != null) {
            log.info("Updating bulk fcm log for batch id: {}, admin: {}", adminFcmResource.getId(), adminUser);
            fcmDetail = batchFcmRepository.findOne(adminFcmResource.getId());
            fcmDetail.setStatus(adminFcmResource.getStatus());
            fcmDetail.setCreatedBy(adminFcmResource.getAdminId());
            fcmDetail.setImagePath(adminFcmResource.getImagePath());
            fcmDetail.setLogo(adminFcmResource.getLogo());
            if (!InputUtil.isEmpty(adminFcmResource.getTopic())) {
                fcmDetail.setFcmTopics(fcmTopicsService.findByName(adminFcmResource.getTopic()));
            } else {
                fcmDetail.setCsvPath(adminFcmResource.getCsvPath());
            }
        } else {
            log.info("Adding bulk fcm log with csv path: {}, admin: {}", adminFcmResource.getCsvPath(), adminUser);
            fcmDetail = new BatchFcm(adminFcmResource.getTitle(),
                    adminFcmResource.getMessage(),
                    adminFcmResource.getImagePath(),
                    adminFcmResource.getAdminId(),
                    adminFcmResource.getExternalRedirectUrl());
            if (!InputUtil.isEmpty(adminFcmResource.getTopic())) {
                fcmDetail.setFcmTopics(fcmTopicsService.findByName(adminFcmResource.getTopic()));
            } else {
                fcmDetail.setCsvPath(adminFcmResource.getCsvPath());
            }
            fcmDetail.setLogo(adminFcmResource.getLogo());
            fcmDetail.setForScheduling(false);
        }
        fcmDetail.setFcmType(FCMTypes.OFFERS.ordinal());
        fcmDetail.setCreatedBy(AuthUtil.getCurrentUser().getId());
        batchFcmRepository.save(fcmDetail);
```

The `findByName` does have a `@Cacheable` though.
Is there a way to save the data? and also keep the id in the column.
I have done `@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "fcm_topics_id")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the version in database table as hibernate tries to update the transient  property on the basis of version.

Comment: Yes, my version was NULL , then i changed it 0, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that i see here is that you are missing the @id annotation in both entities. 
It can happen, that even your topic already exists in your DB, hibernate doesnt see the id, and thinks it is a new entry, that has to be inserted. 
Try to add the id fields in your entities.

Comment: The id annotation is present in the `AbstractEntity`

Comment: Are you using @Transactional annotation on your method?

Answer (score 0):

Means that you forget to save state of the object

Comment: I tried using `CascadeType.PERSIST` or `CascadeType.ALL` but due to the `unique =true` a ConstraintViolationException occurs. It does save the instance, doesnt it?